# How do I do auth for SPA + API?

Tags: authentication, authorization, single-page-application, openid-connect, standards

Okay, so long question ahead.

I'm working on an Angular + .NET Core app and I'm a little confused as to what is the best way to do authN & authZ for my app.
For a while before, what I would do is have a page on my frontend which requests the E-mail and Password and send it via POST to my backend, where I would generate a JWT Token. Then, I would store this token in the `localStorage` and use it for requests.

But, after reading some articles, I noticed that people tend to do it in another way. From what I understand, it goes something like:

1. Create a traditional auth app
2. When the user wants to log in on the SPA, redirect them to the auth app, where they log in
3. After logging in, redirect back to SPA and store the token in memory
4. Use the stored token to authenticate & authorize requests
5. Profit

I've also been reading and getting into using Auth0, which seems to be using the latter approach. My problem with Auth0 currently is that I need to have an `Users` table in my local database for things like getting additional user data *(I know about the metadata that can be added in Auth0, but isn't it slower to have to get data from Auth0 everytime I need to use user metadata?)* & relationships, but the Hooks don't work when my app is on localhost.

Anyways,

**TL;DR**

- Is there a standard way of doing this that is currently recommended everyone does
- Do I understand correctly how the latter approach actually works
- Is the way I was doing auth that insecure? From what I understand, the insecurity comes from storing the JWT Token in localStorage, but the token actually needs a secret key to be generated, so does it matter if an ill-intentioned user can see their token? They can't tamper with it without the secret anyways

Answer (score 0):

I would check out these two resources and I do agree with the conclusion to put all of the token handling in the backend, not in the SPA client.

- [alert‘OAuth 2 0’; // The impact of XSS on OAuth 2 0 in SPAs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&ab_channel=PhilippeDeRyck)
- [SPAs are dead!?](https://leastprivilege.com/2020/03/31/spas-are-dead/)